# Why this instance creation of reqpro40.applicationclass fails?

Tags: c#, .net, interop, objectinstantiation

I am trying to open a ReqPro project from c# class code. The steps followed are:

1. Add reference to ReqPro.dll (the extensibility COM dll)
2. Create a type of ReqPro40.Application and have an instance of ReqPro40.ApplicationClass like:

   ```
   ReqPro40.Application appReqPro = new ApplicationClass();
   ReqPro40.Project prjReqPro;
   prjReqPro = appReqPro.OpenProject(@"D:\MyReqPro\MyReqPro.rqs", ReqPro40.enumOpenProjectOptions.eOpenProjOpt_RQSFile, "admin", "admin", ReqPro40.enumProjectFlags.eProjFlag_Normal, ReqPro40.enumRelatedProjectOptions.eRelatedProjOption_ConnectNone);
   ```

The code compiles well, but when run (I wrote a simple Unit test), it fails saying `"Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.ReqPro40, Version=1.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"Interop.ReqPro40, Version=1.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"`.

**Update1:**

I tried it on my laptop, and it worked fine. I have ReqPro installed on my laptop. But it does not work on the server (Windows 2008 Enterprise). I connect to the server using remote connection. Any clue?

**Update for bounty**

I shall expect some working code with steps to recreate.

Comment: Has ReqPro been properly installed on the server?

Comment: Yes, it is installed. I can connect to the server using remote connection and from the start menu, open the project without any issue.

Comment: Obvious question - is D:\MyReqPro\MyReqPro.rqs valid on the server?

Comment: Yes, it is valid and I can open it using ReqPro installed on the server with the same credentials as put in the code.

Comment: Are the versions on your laptop and the server the same?

Comment: Try this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: @The Evil Greebo: The versions are same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check on the server that the ReqPro.dll is in the root folder, sometimes the referenced dll's dont copy to the bin folder. You can also specify a "Probing" element in your app.config file to specify subfolders that the CLR can search to locate a referenced assembly if it cannot find the assembly.

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
       <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schmas-AWorks-cam:asm.v1">
           <probling privatePath="bin\Ordersbin;Extbin"/>
       </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Update:
If you arn't already I would suggest you use a Setup Project to Install your Project, this will make sure any 3rd party dlls, automatically get copied to the root folder were the application is installed.

Comment: Oh good, I was running out of ideas - should have thought of something so simple!  Here I was all going down the COM DLL registration problem path ... :)

Comment: But, I still have an issue. I was trying to test the functionality using unit test (MS Unit). While the code now runs from the unit test, it does not run if I invoke it from a windows form. Can you please help out?

Comment: @The Evil Greebo: You might be right. The issue is yet to be solved.

Comment: Are you getting any kind of Exception or error when you run it from windows form?

Comment: Assuming your unit test is in a separate project from the windows form, have you verified that all of your references in both projects are *exactly* identical (down to the version and file paths etc)?